# Python list of Objects taking up too much memory

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, memory

I have the following code, that creates a million objects of a class foo:

```
for i in range(1000000):
    bar = foo()
    list_bar.append(bar)
```

The bar object is only 96 bytes, as determined by `getsizeof()`. However, the append step takes almost 8GB of ram. Once the code exits the loop, the ram usage drops to expected amounts (size of the list + some overhead ~103MB). Only while the loop is running does the ram usage skyrocket. Why does this happen? Any workarounds?
PS: Using a generator is not an option, it has to be a list.

**EDIT:** `xrange` doesn't help, using Python 3. The memory usage stays high only during the loop execution, and drops after the loop is through. Could `append` have some non-obvious overhead?

Comment: Why is using `xrange` (a generator) instead of `range` not an option?  A list with a million elements *will* take up a lot of RAM; there's no way around that.

Comment: `list_bar = [foo() for _ in xrange(1000000)]` will reduce the memory overhead, and make your code more idiomatic.

Comment: When you say "it has to be a list", do you mean that `list_bar` has to be a list? Or that the result of the `for` loop condition expression (i.e., `range`) must be a list?

Comment: Unless you provide more information, the question might get closed for not being clear.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @sapi xrange has no noticeable effect here. My question was why the append step took up so much memory; after the loop execution, the list size is ~100MB, as expected. 
@jonrsharpe Tried, no change in memory usage.
@Kevin list_bar has to be a list, I simply need a million objects of type `foo`. I also tried using a tuple, the problem persists.

Comment: In many cases getsizeof() doesn't return you the real size of an object.

Comment: @SrivathsanJayaraman: Yes, appending / list-resizing has some overhead, but not _that_ much. FWIW, here's the relevant C source: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listobject.c ; in particular, see the `list_resize()` function. Does antti's `gc.collect()` trick help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably this is due to some unintended **cyclical** references made by the `foo()` constructor; as normally Python objects will release memory instantly when the reference count drops to zero; now these would be freed later when the garbage collector gets a chance to run.

You can try to force the GC run after say 10000 iterations to see if it keeps the memory usage constant.

```
import gc
n = 1000000
list_bar = [ None ] * n
for i in range(n):
    list_bar[i] = foo()
    if i % 10000 == 0:
        gc.collect()
```

If this relieves memory pressure then the memory usage is because of some reference cycles.

---

The resizing of a list has some overhead. If you know how many elements, then you can create the list beforehand, e.g.:

```
list_bar = [ foo() for _ in xrange(1000000) ]
```

should know the size of the array and not need to resize it; or create the list filled with `None`:

```
n = 1000000
list_bar = [ None ] * n
for i in range(n):
    list_bar[i] = foo()
```

---

`append` should be using `realloc` to grow the list, but old memory ought to be released as soon as possible; and all in all the overhead of all memory allocated should not sum to 8G for a list that is 100 MB at the end; it can be possible that the operating system is miscalculating the memory used.

Comment: Hey, the length of the list is known. I already tried creating a list of dummy elements and replacing them as such, it doesn't help. I'm starting to think this has less to do with `append` and more to do with the `foo` class; the class inherits a third party module that might be causing problems.
It's definitely not a miscalculation, tested on two separate computers.

Comment: Thanks, turns out there _was_ a cyclic reference in there.

Answer (score 1):

How are you measuring the memory usage?

I suspect your usage of a 3rd party module might be the cause. Perhaps the 3rd party module is temporarily using a lot of memory when initialised.

Besides, `sys.getsizeof()` is not an accurate indication of the memory used by an object.

For example:

```
from sys import getsizeof

class A(object):
    pass

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.big = 'a' * 1024*1024*1024    # approx. 1 GiB

>>> getsizeof(A)
976
>>> a = A()
>>> getsizeof(a)
64
>>> 
>>> getsizeof(B)
976
>>> b = B()
>>> getsizeof(b)
64
>>> getsizeof(b.big)
1073741873
```

After instantiating `b = B()`, `top` reports approx 1GiB resident memory usage. Obviously this is not reflected by `getsizeof(b)` which returns only 64 bytes.